# Given any two real numbers x<y, we can find a rational number q such that x<q<y.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, self-learning, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

> Given any two real numbers $x<y$, we can find a rational number $q$ such that $x<q<y$. Hint: use the fact that for any $x\in R, \exists N \in Z$ such that $x>1/N$ and argue by contradiction (Terence Tao-Analysis $1$).

Following the hint:
$y-x \in R => y-x > 1/N$ for some positive integer $N$. Also, since $y-x > 0 => y-x>c$ for some $c>0, c\in Z$.

Here the real number is defined by a formal symbol $LIM_{n \to \infty} a_n$, where $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence of rationals.

We have, for every $\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1 > 0$:
$x = LIM_{n\to \infty} a_n, y = LIM_{n\to \infty}b_n$,
$i,j > N_0, |a_i-a_j| < \epsilon_0$ since $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence
$i,j > N_1, |b_i-b_j| < \epsilon_1$ since $b_n$ is a Cauchy sequence
$n > N_2, |b_n-a_n| > c$ since $y-x>0$

Suppose there is no such $q$ that satisfies $x<q<y$. Then for every $q \in Q$ such that $q<y$ we should have that $x>q$.
But take $q = (x+y)/2$. We know that $|(x+y)/2-x|=|x/2+y/2|=|a_n+b_n|/2$. Since it is a positive real number then $|a_n+b_n|/2 > 1/N$ for some $N \in Z, N > 0$. Therefore, we get that $\exists q\in Q$ such that $q-x>0=>q>x$. Thus, we got the contradiction we wanted.

Comment: Why do you say that $y-x\in\mathbb R\implies y-x>\frac1N$ for some $N\in\mathbb N$? This is false.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I am using that for any positive real number x > 0 there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $x > 1/N > 0$. By Archimedian property. Here $y-x>0$

Comment: You did not write that $y-x>0$. You only wrote that $y-x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: You write "Here the real number is defined by a formal limit symbol..." What do you mean by "the real number" in this sentence?  You should identify said number with a variable so we know what you're talking about.  

Nevermind your proof, do you have some intuition for why this result it true?  Have you thought about why there should be a rational number lurking in any gap on the number line?  This intuition is important.

Comment: Your proof is not far away.  I recommend, rather than writing "for every $ \epsilon_0, \epsilon_1 > 0 $ ... " you choose specific, useful values.  I recommend something like $ (y-x) / 4 $.  If you draw a picture, you will see why!  Intuition is so important for learning to write proofs.  Good luck!

Comment: Rather than the language about "formal limits," I think it would suffice to say "Let $ a_n $ be a sequence of rationals approaching $ x $ and $ b_n $ be a sequence of rationals approaching $ y $," though your professor might prefer the more formal language (assuming you are a student, perhaps incorrectly).

Comment: One last comment, and then I'm leaving: you write, "Suppose there is no such $ q $.  Then we could have two cases...", and you go on to talk about $ q $!  Two things: (1), you don't need a proof by contradiction here!, and (2), it does not make sense to talk about $ q $ immediately after assuming such $ q $ does not exist.  

Rather, the point of this proof is that you can directly construct a rational number $ q $ between $ x $ and $ y $.